# Why is mysql date_format function returning a result 45 minutes different from the input time?

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql 5.7 on RDS and I executed query.
there is 45 mins difference between input and output. I want to know why I got the wrong result.

```
select css_regDate 
from j2t_counsel_sms 
where date_format(css_regDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') = '2022-02-18 09:02:53';
```

and I got result like below

```
css_regDate
'2022-02-18 09:47:53'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, compare ignoring fractional seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Your date format is wrong. With the datetime of `2022-02-18 09:47:53`, a format of `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'` would translate it to `2022-02-18 09:02:53`. You are using `%m` for both month and minute, whereas you should be using `%i` for minute instead. Your final statement should be along the lines of:

```
SELECT css_regDate 
FROM j2t_counsel_sms 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(css_regDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') = '2022-02-18 09:02:53';
```

For a full list of the format details, you can look at [the MYSQL DATE_FORMAT documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)'s table. For this instance:

> | Specifier | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | %i | Minutes, numeric (00..59) |